# Java byte representation in String

Tags: java, android, byte

I am receiving data from a hardware device. I receive it as an array of bytes. I want to build and store a String that can show me the data of the array of bytes. This is what I have:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
String[] str = new String[bytes];
StringBuffer readMessage = new StringBuffer();

for(int i=0; i<bytes; ++i){
  str[i] = Integer.toHexString(buffer[i]);
   while (str[i].length() < 8){  //standarize size 
     str[i] = '0' + str[i];    
   }
  readMessage.append(str[i]);
}
```

The main problem that I have is that I am receiving unexpected bytes when I transform the bytes to String. I am receiving pure bytes so I am expecting the values to range from 0x00 to 0xFF. However, some of the bytes are transformed to bytes like 0xFFFFFF09. Why is this happening??

Comment: Not related to your problem, but what happens if `mmInStream.read(buffer)` returns `-1`?

Comment: How about [`new String(buffer, 0, bytes)` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6//docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[], int, int))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert `byte` to `int` this way:

```
int byteAsInt = ((int)buffer[i]) & 0x000000FF;
str[i] = Integer.toHexString(byteAsInt);
```

Comment: FWIW, the leading zeros on the literal are unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. Just wanted to make this example to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

byte is a signed data type, so 0xFF is -1. When converting to a larger integral type it will still be -1, i.e. 0xFFFF or 0xFFFFFFFF for 16 and 32 bit integer values.

**Edit:**

If you want to get the unsigned value, do a bitwise AND (&) with 0xFF when assigning to a larger variable.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore the sign and get the byte representation as is??

Comment: If you want to get the unsigned value, do a bitwise AND (`&`) with 0xFF when assigning to a larger variable.

Answer (score 0):

Without running your code I suppose that your problem is in your inner loop.

while (str[i].length() < 8){  //standarize size 
     str[i] = '0' + str[i];
   }

What would you like to achieve? Print `0xFF` instead of `FF`? In this case just modify one line as following:

`str[i] = "0x" + Integer.toHexString(buffer[i]);`

and remove the inner loop.

Comment: The problem is that sometimes I get the byte representation to be 8 characters long as "FFFFFF68" for those that are not the same size I just want them all to have the same size.